# Does Composer not support comments in requriements.txt?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

This is my `requirements.txt`

```
# This is a comment
python-json-logger==2.0.4

# Here's a private package
my_private_pypi_package==1.2.3
```

I get an error:

```
> gcloud composer environments update myenv  --format=json --project myproj --location=us-central1 --update-pypi-packages-from-file='requirements.txt'

ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Found 2 problems:

    1) Error validating key # Here's a private package. PyPI dependency name is not formatted properly. It must follow the format of 'identifier' specified in PEP-508.
    2) Error validating key # This is a comment. PyPI dependency name is not formatted properly. It must follow the format of 'identifier' specified in PEP-508.
```

Seems like it's doing some pretty crude validation.

Does Composer really not support valid requirements.txt's with comments? Is there a way to add them Composer won't choke on?

## Edit

I opened a bug tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295764408

I commented on the GitHub issue mentioned here that this is still a bug: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this before and as I can remember, an internal bug has been fixed regarding this; as what was stated there: `"Skip commented lines when reading in requirements file"`. I suggest to file an [issue report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) regarding this for them to know why this bug is still existing or reoccurred.

Also, the workaround in this is to delete the comment line(s) to remove the error since it begins with # character, and requirements.txt must follow the [format specified in PEP-508](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#before_you_begin:%7E:text=Requirements%20must%20follow%20the%20format%20specified%20in%20PEP%2D508%20where%20each%20requirement%20is%20specified%20in%20lowercase%20and%20consists%20of%20the%20package%20name%20with%20optional%20extras%20and%20version%20specifiers.).

Comment: I opened a bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295764408. The issue linked to though appears to be for a composer.json config file.